# whats the difference between using amqp backend and database backend for Celery results?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I don't understand where the actual results are getting stored in either case.
I am using **django-celery** and **sqlite** as my database in a test application. I am using **RabbitMQ** as my broker.

I tried setting `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"` and also to "database" with `CELERY_RESULT_DBURI="mysqlitedb"`

But I don't understand how to interact with the results once they are stored, in either case.

I think I fail to understand the basic concepts surrounding what happens to a result once the worker returns at the end of a task.

Comment: Are you asking how to directly interact with the data in the database?  I suspect that the database is just used to store the queue and use blocking transactions to create distributed locks.  I would not expect there to be any useful persistent data.  That is just my best guess, I have no direct knowledge of celery internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are sending task to celery, you get `AsyncResult` as a result. It has an `id` attribute which you can store somewhere and then use [result](http://ask.github.com/celery/reference/celery.result.html) to check and retrieve actual result of task execution.

Result storage is AMQP or database table. First is faster and do not add load on DB but needs some additional setup.

Comment: yabut. Who and what holds the result, and how is a database backend dif than a amqp backend. If you wait a long time before you decide to look at the result, it will have to been stored somewhere. Task_id for Celery 2.5 - The stable release.

Comment: Then I don't understand what the question is. Result storage is AMQP or database table. First is faster and do not add load on DB but needs some additional setup. What else?

Comment: edit you answer to reflect your comments so i can undownvote and check you off. Yes my question was not clear. I was not clear as to where results are actually stored in django-celery or how to interact with results in an ORM way. Or what to do with them as they pile up in the db.